# How to select the Angular grid-controller row in selenium with webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working on automation test framework in selenium java.
In my test application we have used **angular grid-controller**.

How to access grid row to perform few operations?[image: Grid in Angular JS]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the answer myself,
For every angular grid , angular generates the column index(hex number) , which is appended to the class attribute of the tag.
So we can access the cell value with same class attribute and  and iterate through all the rows for the **host name** column as shown in image please find the code snippet in selenium for same:

[image]

```
[![List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-disable-selection ui-grid-coluiGrid-0006')]//div"));
    int iSize = rows.size();
for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++) {
                String sValue =  "192.168.30.70";
                if (sValue.equalsIgnoreCase(inputtext)) {
                    rows.get(i).click();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

so in this way we can search the particular grid column for the matching value.

Comment: Thanks, but how to proceed if I want to edit the rows.get(i) value instead of just a click() ?

Comment: If I want to select a row and row is not in view then what option I can use? Ag grid I think does not render rows until they are in view that is they are not part of page dom. Therefore finding the row is failing in Selenium Java

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and somehow it didn't work for me, it didn't click the row or it didn't do anything. Here's a screenshot of my application: 
 [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBmUj.png)

And here is my code:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'ui-grid-cell hoverable-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-0084')]//div"));
int iSize = rows.size();
for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++) {
    String sValue =  "MATT";
    if (sValue.equalsIgnoreCase("matt")) {
         rows.get(i).click();
         break;
    }
}
```